# Limit post meta to specific template

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to limit the post meta to specific template.

This code seems to do the trick

```
$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
$template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
```

but when running a debug I get the Undefined index: post_ID/post error.

Is there an alternative or can you help me fix this?

EDIT:

Wrapped whole code with `if (isset($_GET['post']))` and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  You can't combine multiple tags to create a new concept.  That is, combining `post` and `meta` doesn't mean you're talking about the Wordpress `get_post_meta` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your ternary to avoid a warning you probably want

```
$post_id = isset($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
```

Which will check to see if the value post exists in `$_GET['post']` before trying to do this, while not raising a warning.

Comment: Yea that fixed the undefined index: post_ID/post problem but now the $post_id is undefined.

Answer (score -2):

`Undefined index` does not indicate an error. It simply means that the variable `$_POST['post_ID']` does not exist. You should add this to hide notices:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```